# Googleplus logout is not working in android application

Tags: java, android

In my application and using google plus login,the login functionality is working fine but i can't able to google plus logout from the application am using navigation drawer for my application so please help me...

***Login Class***

```
    public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
            ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

        private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
        // Logcat tag
        private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";

        // Profile pic image size in pixels
        private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;

        // Google client to interact with Google API
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

        /**
         * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
         * from starting further intents.
         */
        private boolean mIntentInProgress;

        private boolean mSignInClicked;

        private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

        private SignInButton btnSignIn;
        private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
        private ImageView imgProfilePic;
        private TextView txtName, txtEmail;
        private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

            btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
            btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
            btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
            imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
            txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
            llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);

            // Button click listeners
            btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
                    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
        }

        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Method to resolve any signin errors
         * */
        private void resolveSignInError() {
            if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    mIntentInProgress = true;
                    mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    mIntentInProgress = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
            if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                        0).show();
                return;
            }

            if (!mIntentInProgress) {
                // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
                mConnectionResult = result;

                if (mSignInClicked) {
                    // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
                    // resolve all
                    // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                    resolveSignInError();
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    mSignInClicked = false;
                }

                mIntentInProgress = false;

                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
            Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Get user's information
        //  getProfileInformation();

            // Update the UI after signin
            updateUI(true);

        }

        /**
         * Updating the UI, showing/hiding buttons and profile layout
         * */
        private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
            if (isSignedIn) {
                btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Intent gd=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(gd);
                /*btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/
            } else {
                btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                /*btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
            }
        }

        /**
         * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
         * */
        /*private void getProfileInformation() {
            try {
                if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                    Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                            .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                    String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                    String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                    String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                    String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                    Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                            + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                            + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

                    txtName.setText(personName);
                    txtEmail.setText(email);

                    // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
                    // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
                    // replacing sz=X
                    personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                            personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                            + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

                    new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }*/

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            updateUI(false);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Button on click listener
         * */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_sign_in:
                // Signin button clicked
                signInWithGplus();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_sign_out:
                // Signout button clicked
                /*signOutFromGplus();*/
                break;
            case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
                // Revoke access button clicked
                revokeGplusAccess();
                break;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Sign-in into google
         * */
        private void signInWithGplus() {
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mSignInClicked = true;
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Sign-out from google
         * */
        /*private void signOutFromGplus() {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                updateUI(false);
            }
        }*/

        /**
         * Revoking access from google
         * */
        private void revokeGplusAccess() {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                                updateUI(false);
                            }

                        });
            }
        }

        /**
         * Background Async task to load user profile picture from url
         * */
        private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            ImageView bmImage;

            public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
                this.bmImage = bmImage;
            }

            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                String urldisplay = urls[0];
                Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                try {
                    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return mIcon11;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }

    }
```

***Logout Class***

```
public class LogoutFragment extends Fragment{
@Override 
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.logout, container, false);


            return rootView; 

    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do u mean by "not working"?is there any exception or something?

Comment: google plus logout function totally not working in navigation drawer list..how is it clear the problem...

Comment: Improved formatting and separation of two classes